# Should I think about Network Byte Order?

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, network-programming, endianness

I cannot understand the concept of "Network byte order". I have read [Network byte order and endianness issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22889283/4149835), but still cannot.
Now I made a formal network protocol description for a communication between two computers over TCP sockets. Here is the phrase "...use little-endian byte order". But the standard Network byte order is big-endian.

Whether should I think about a byte order, if on both sides of a network the byte order is fully defined, and I write, roughly speakin, `void*` and `size` ? How can a network "know" about my data? What about float types?

For example, whether I cannot write on my side:

```
stream.setDevice(tcpSocket);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
...

struct SomeType
{
    int32_t a;
    int32_t b;
    double c;

    friend QDataStream& operator << (
        QDataStream& stream, const SomeType& x)
    {   
        stream << x.a
            << x.b
            << x.c;

        return stream;
    }        
};
```

or may be just:

```
SomeType x;
tcpSocket.write(&x, size); // If known a byte order and a data structure alignment on both sides
```

Comment: The "network" or the network stack in your computer doesn't know anything about the data you transmit, it just passes sequences of binary blobs back and forth. The trouble comes in *your program* when you have to interpret the data into something that your program can handle. If a big-endian system sends an `int` unmodified to another system which happens to be little-endian, then the receiver will think that the received `int` value is something else than was sent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , Can I don't think about this in my example (if known a byte order and a data structure alignment on both host sides)?

Comment: @VladimirBershov you can but one day this mistake will be a problem. In any case you will see performance and maintenance benefits in using a compressed framing protocol. google's protocol buffers is one such protocol that's freely available.

Comment: Your code will break as soon as you run it on 2 machines with different architectures (e.g. x86 little endian and arm big endian). Both variants, since the `int`s will have a different representation. The second version might even break between different compiler versions, since they might have a different understanding about struct layout (alignments, etc.).

Comment: @Matthias247 , I've changed to int32_t

Comment: @VladimirBershov That doesn fix the problem that when the byte sequence 0x00000001 is transmitted over the wire once machine might interpret it as 1 and another one as 2^24. The only way to avoid this is using a proper serialization, which works platform independent.

Comment: @Matthias247 , but there is anyway still no solution for `float` and `double`

Answer (score 2):

32 bit value represented as little-endian (intel etc):

`address offset   0             1              2                3
               bits 0-7    bits 8-15      bits 16-23       bits 24-31`

---

And represented in network byte order or big-endian (motorola cpus, etc):

`address offset   0             1              2                3
               bits 24-31    bits 16-23      bits 8-15       bits 0-7`

---

Depending on which architecture you first learned to write machine code (if you did) one will make more sense to you than the other. For almost anyone under 45 years old, it will be little-endian which is the opposite of network byte order.

If you learned to write machine code on a Texas TMS9900 architecture like me it's even more confusing because in texas-land, bit 0 is the most significant bit (!)

---

Update:

In general it is better to encode data on the wire in a way that is independent of hardware or compiler implementation choices, or even languages.

Here's an example of such encoding from google's protocol buffers:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

The advantages here are:

1. generally less traffic transmitted so faster networking
2. each end of the connection will understand the data regardless of hardware, compiler version, or even language.

Comment: But what about my case - if known (and clearly defined) a byte order and a data structure alignment on both host sides?

Comment: @VladimirBershov this will tie your code to one specific piece of hardware. Hardware changes over time. Do you still want your code working in 10 years time?

Comment: But if I change `int` s to `int32_t`? And in any case, there is no solution for floating point values

Comment: @VladimirBershov see my update. This is how google do it. I follow their example in my code and as a result my systems can be built from components written in any language. That is helpful when you start to scale your solution.

Comment: ... Thank you for suggesting protocol buffers. It looks like the best solution now. Anyway, If we look globally at the problem, I sure that nowadays it is unacceptable to think about the network byte order

Answer (score 1):

A TCP-socket is just a stream of bytes and don't care at all about the endianness of the data you send. Thus, for your own private network-protocols you can use any byte-order you like. If all the computers that use the protocol has the same natural byte-order it is probably a good idea to use this as the serialization order as this allows you to write code like your second example.